# Edit Mode is not selecting all objects

Tags: edit-mode, select

Edit Mode is not selecting all objects, when i hold the Shift Button, switch to X, Y and Z Asis Camera and select it again it will select more Parts but not all of the Parts how can i select all Parts instandly?

---

[image: Here a Pic:]

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu > select > All or press the A Key. To deselect you can choose in the preferences if to press Alt A or toggle with the same A key.

Comment: Thanks and Where is the Menu? Which menu?

Comment: @NIfwqnqwfinqw "Menu" is usually the top bar of a window...

Answer (score 0):

In edit mode you can use one of the following solutions:

- Your **Keyboard** where you can press the key <kbd>A</kbd> to select all
- The **Menu** in the *top left* part of your screen, you press <kbd>select</kbd> -> <kbd>All</kbd>
- Your **Mouse** to select manually , but check that the toggle x-ray is selected (it's in the up right of the screen).

---

[image: deselected] [image]

In the *first image* the toggle is not active.

In the *second one* is active, as you can understand from the fact the the button is now blue.

Remember always that for images update on a question, you can edit your question and add them there, it makes easier to see everything in the same place, and so to help you to solve your problems